# Pushing new 'observables' to an 'observables' list during application run time and listen to changes using combineLatest - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've a situation where I have a list of observables that being contently updated by pushing new observables to there during th application runtime.
On that list I'm doing `combineLatest` and perform API call with the latest emit.
This all logic happens inside my designated service.

My problem is that I can't understand where/when I should subscribe to that list.
I've tried to subscribe inside the contractor but it seems that nothing happens when the observables emites new data. my question is:

How can I'm update this list during the application runtime and combine the latest changes?
My code looks something like the follow:

```
export class myService {
  private myListOfObserables: Observables<any> = []

  constractur() {
    combineLatest(this.myListOfObserables).pipe(
     concatMap((res) => // Call API and wait for response before sending a new one)
    )
  }

  public uodateListOfObs(obs, name) {
    if (name === 'someValue') {
      this.myListOfObserables.push(obs)
    }
  }
}
```

**Important note:**
Inside the `concatMap` I'm calling the API and must to wait for a response before sending a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create BehaviorSubject and emit your observables array to it. So, you can subscribe on it and then switch to combineLatest with latest value of array. Something like this:

```
export class MyService {
    private observables = [];
    private sources$ = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<YOUR_TYPE>[]>([]);

    constructor() {
        this.sources$.pipe(
            switchMap(observables => combineLatest(observables))
        ).subscribe(() => //do something);
    }

    addObservable(name, observable) {
        if (name === 'someValue') {
            this.observables.push(observable);
            this.sources$.next(this.observables);
        }
    }
}
```